# Chrome Zoom as media query

Tags: css, google-chrome, media-queries

How do we force the browser (only chrome) to zoom if media queries requirement are met?
If one is too lazy to do all the media queries is there a way to force or imitate the browser zoom if it's efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `window.matchMedia`, which lets you approximate media queries in javascript.

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)")) {
  document.body.style.zoom = 1.5;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia
https://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia